# Auto change HS popup height based on dynamic content

Tags: highslide

Having a HS popup opened. After some actions the content inside the popup is changed (added content).

And a scroll bar will appear in order to navigate through the content.

How can I automatically resize or change height of the popup according to the new content and in this way no scroll bar will appear?

I suppose the height of the content is calculated upon firing "hs.htmlExpand".

I need same - determine the content height, but for an opened popup.

Comment: Have you tried to use `resizeTo()` function to make more space? See [docs](http://highslide.com/ref/hs.Expander.prototype.resizeTo). Another solution will be `reflow()` function: [docs](http://highslide.com/ref/hs.Expander.prototype.reflow). Note to use Expander, you need highslide-full.js file.

Comment: Paweł: thanks. resizeTo - Resizes the popup to a given width and height. I nmy case I don't know the new hright of the popup, it's dynamic and depends how much content I add to popup. reflow seems to do what I need, I will try it.

Comment: Paweł: yes, reflow is what I need, thank you! You can post it to "answer" section and I will accept the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible options:

- `resizeTo()` [function](http://highslide.com/ref/hs.Expander.prototype.resizeTo) - in case width and height is known
- `reflow()` [function](http://highslide.com/ref/hs.Expander.prototype.reflow) - in case container should be fluid

Note to use Expander functions, highslide-full.js file is required.